# How do I use math to calculate the percentages of multiple random events happening

Tags: probability, statistics, random, percentages

I'm creating a mod to a video game that will list the percent chance of an event happening. I know how to get individual percentages, but not a total percentage of the events.

## The Problem:

So there is this pool, or an array of possible outcomes.
`Classic` starts in this pool so hence it's always in the pool.

`Bifurcated` has a 15% chance of being added to that pool
`Golden` has a 0.3% chance of being added
`Meaty` has a 10% multiplied by the amount of X upgraded, to be added. `X=(max 3, min 0)`
`Caramelized` has a 2% chance to be added.

And if another certain upgrade has been bought, all BUT the `Classic` get their checks done again, so there is a chance that there is : two, one, or none of each of the four being added to the pool.

Now the game takes this pool, and chooses one randomly from it. They have equal chances once in the pool. But not equal chances to enter the pool.

## My Attempts

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to write the math to automatically calculate the chances are for each item. For example, if it was just `Classic` and `Bifurcated` a 15% chance to be added then a 50% chance to be selected would be 7.5% chance while classic has a 92.5% chance. But once I  get to the possibility of a third being added, how do I calculate that?

After a lot of thinking, I came up with this list of percentages of JUST adding them to the random pool.

```
//chances of just ADDING bifurcated to the pool.
//RAN ONCE
ranOnce_addOne = 0.15;
ranOnce_addNone = 0.85;
//RAN TWICE
ranTwice_addNone = 0.7225;
ranTwice_addTwo = 0.0225;
ranTwice_addOne = 0.225;
```

I had this, and didn't know where to go from here. For example if we only checked to add `bifurcated` to the pool once, I could figure it out, but the fact there are times when the amount in the pool *could* go from 1 to 9 (though statistically unlikely).

Now I have access to the amount of `X` and whether the checks get ran twice or not. But I have no idea how to code something that will tell me what is the chances of all this?

> I originally asked on StackOverflow as I'm a programmer not a math guy, so I did some searches on this site to see if my question was already answered, but didn't find any nor could I understand half of what I read. Sorry

Comment: Ummm... what's a "mod"?

Comment: Edited, a mod to a video game. Irrelevant... but basically I need the percentages and I don't know where or how to start

Comment: Ummm... what's a "mod to a video game"?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork A "modification" to the game. Basically some sort of script or something else that will modify a game's settings, behavior, gameplay, etc. As mentioned by OP, this is completely irrelevant to the question and just for background context.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork  Really? Um basically people adding or changing code to a video game so it works differently. I want to make a Quality of Life improvement by showing the statistics of an event occuring. For more on what is a "mod to a video game": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_game_modding

Comment: That being said, this has certainly gotta be Cookie Clicker :D

Comment: @AidenChow you know it! 

Comment: What is you problem: just decide if you add `bifurcated` to the pool with probability $0.15$ (use random number generator for this).

Comment: @user I can't "just" decide to add bifurcated to the pool. It has a 0.15% chance of being added, to the pool. With another option, it checks again, so TWO 0.15% chances of being added to the pool. So a possibility of a pool looking like `classic` or `classic, bifurcated` or even `classic, bifurcated, bifurcated` How do I determine chances of this?
But then `meaty`, `golden`, and `carmelized` all have their own chances

Comment: Exatcly this was said: decide to add `bifurcated` to the pool with probability $0.15$ (use random number generator for this). Do the same for other items (with corresponding probabilities).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\widetilde S$ be the "pool" of possible outcomes that you call "Classic" etc., and let these possible outcomes be denoted as $A_1,...,A_k$. The interesting feature here is that $\widetilde S$ is a *random subset* of $\Omega=\{A_1,...,A_k\}$, each element being included (resp. excluded) with probability $p_i:=P(A_i)$ (resp. $1-p_i$). Thus, first $\widetilde S$ is chosen randomly, then an element $X$ is chosen uniformly at random from $\widetilde S$.

A useful coding scheme is to represent each subset by a binary string $(b_1...b_k)$, with $b_i$ equaling $1$ (or $0$) according to whether element $A_i$ is (or is not) included in the subset. Thus the subset coded by $(b_1...b_k)$ has probability given by

$$P(b_1...b_k)=p_1^{(b_1)}...p_k^{(b_k)}$$

with the special notation

$$p^{(b)}:=\begin{cases}
p &\text{if $b=1$}\\
1-p &\text{if $b=0$}\end{cases}$$

Then

$$\begin{align}P(X=A_i)
&= \sum_S P(X=A_i\mid \widetilde S=S)\ P(\widetilde S=S)\\[1ex]
&= \sum_{S\ni A_i} {1\over |S|}\ P(\widetilde S=S)\\[1ex]
&= \sum_{(b_1..b_k);b_i=1} {p_1^{(b_1)}...p_k^{(b_k)}\over \sum_i b_i}\\[1ex]
\end{align}$$

Here's a Python program that does this:

```
from itertools import product
from math import prod

def prob(i, P):
    """return P(X=A_i) given P=[P_1,...,P_n]"""
    i = i-1; lenP = len(P)
    bin_words = product([0,1], repeat=lenP)
    return sum(1/sum(b)*prod((P[i] if b[i] else 1-P[i]) for i in range(lenP)) for b in bin_words if b[i])
```

Example:

```
P = [1, 0.15, 0.003, 0.10, 0.02]
PX = [prob(i,P) for i in range(len(P))]
print(f"{PX=}")
print(f"{sum(PX)=}")

output:
PX=[0.009182871666666665, 0.8703468466666666, 0.071954455, 0.0013699549999999997, 0.04714587166666667]
sum(PX)=1.0
```